Remove Managed Licenses via Apex
Getting error on Query like Unexpected token '('. at line 33 column 22. I tried many variations but not able to proceed post it. Can someone help?
global class CiscoLicRemovalInactiveUsers implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful {
    private integer totalCount = 0;
    private integer countSuccessRecs = 0;
    private integer countFailRecs = 0;
    private Id systemAdminId;
    private string ManagedPkg = 'CNX';
    private Integer failedJobException;
    private final String METHOD_EXECUTE = 'execute';
    private final String CLASSNAME = 'CiscoLicRemovalInactiveUsers';
    List<ExceptionLog__c> exceptionList = new List<ExceptionLog__c>();
    List<String> failedRemoval = new List<String>();
    global CiscoLicRemovalInactiveUsers(){

        systemAdminId = [Select Sys_UserId__c FROM A_System_User__c Limit 1].Sys_UserId__c;
        failedJobException = 0;
    }
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        //Set<String> srStatus = new Set<String>{'Closed'};
        String query = '';
        if(Test.isRunningTest()){
            query = 'SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Origin = \'semester\'';
        }else{

            query = [(SELECT ID FROM UserPackageLicense WHERE (PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix = :ManagedPkg) AND UserID in (Select id from user where isactive=false))];
        }
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<UserPackageLicense> records){
        try{
            List<UserPackageLicense> LicsToBeRemoved = new List<UserPackageLicense>();
            if(records != null && records.size() > 0){
                totalCount = records.size();
                for(UserPackageLicense UPL : records){
                    LicsToBeRemoved.add(UPL);
                }
                if(LicsToBeRemoved != null && LicsToBeRemoved.size() > 0){
                    Database.DeleteResult[] removalList = Database.delete(LicsToBeRemoved,false);
                    if(removalList != null && removalList.size() > 0){
                        for(Integer i=0; i < removalList.size(); i++ ) {
                            if(removalList[i].isSuccess()) {
                                countSuccessRecs++;
                            } else if(!removalList[i].isSuccess()) {
                                countFailRecs++;
                                failedRemoval.add(LicsToBeRemoved[i].UserID);
                                Database.Error errors =  removalList[i].getErrors().get(0);
                                ExceptionLog__c newExc = new ExceptionLog__c();
                                newExc.ClassName__c = CLASSNAME;
                                newExc.Exception_Source__c = LicsToBeRemoved[i].Id;
                                newExc.MethodNAme__C = METHOD_EXECUTE;
                                newExc.ExceptionType__c = UTIL_ErCon.DML_EXCEPTION;
                                newExc.ExceptionLogTimestamp__c = System.Now();
                                newExc.ExceptionDescription__c = errors.getMessage();
                                newExc.ExceptionDetails__c  = 'Error while removing license from User record(s) : ' + errors.getStatusCode() + ': ' + errors.getMessage();
                                exceptionList.add(newExc);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(exceptionList.size() > 0) {
                Database.insert(exceptionList,false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            UTIL_Logser.logHandledException(ex,userinfo.getOrganizationId(),null,CLASSNAME,METHOD_EXECUTE,null,LoggingLevel.ERROR);
            failedJobException = failedJobException + 1;
        }
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Status, ExtendedStatus, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = : BC.getJobId() and TotalJobItems >=1 LIMIT 1];
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {};
        A_CustomSetting__c CS = A_CustomSetting__c.getOrgDefaults();
        toAddresses.add(CS.A_ProdSupport_DL__c);
        List<Email_Notification__c> emailNotification = [Select EmailIds__c from Email_Notification__c where Process_Type__c =: UTIL_Cons.cisco];
        if(emailNotification != null && !emailNotification.isEmpty()) {
            for(Email_Notification__c email : emailNotification){
                if(email.EmailIds__c != null){
                    List<String> emailIds_SendAck = new List<String>(email.EmailIds__c.split(UTIL_Cons.COMMA_DELIMETER));
                    for(String emlId : emailIds_SendAck) {
                        toAddresses.add(emlId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('CiscoLicRemovalInactiveUsers Batch ' + a.Status);
        if(failedJobException != 0){
            mail.setPlainTextBody('CiscoLicRemovalInactiveUsers processed ' + a.TotalJobItems + ' with failed Jobs '+ failedJobException + '.' + '\n' + totalCount + ' case records picked up for update.' + '\n' + countSuccessRecs + ' case records were updated Successfully and ' + countFailRecs + ' case records update failed.' + '\n' + 'Please review the failed case records (if any): ' + failedRemoval + '.' + '\n' + 'Also review the exception logs captured.');
        }else {
            mail.setPlainTextBody('CiscoLicRemovalInactiveUsers job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems + ' with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.'
            + '\n' + totalCount + ' User records picked for License removal'
            + '\n' + countSuccessRecs + ' Licenses were removed Successfully and ' + countFailRecs + ' Cico License Removal failed.'
            + '\n' + 'Please review the failed User record (if any): UserID (s)' + failedRemoval + '.'
            + '\n' + 'Also review the Exception Logs captured.');
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}


Plz ignore the query on Case running as Test

The error is because 'query` is a String so you need to enclose the following string in single quotes.

An inline query is not a string. Also, queries can't be surrounded by (). Just return the query locator directly:
if(Test.isRunningTest()){
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Origin = 'Semester']);
}else{
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
      [SELECT ID 
       FROM UserPackageLicense 
       WHERE (PackageLicense.NamespacePrefix = :ManagedPkg) AND 
         UserID in (Select id from user where isactive=false)
    ]);
}

In general, you don't need to use a dynamic query string if there are no dynamic elements to the query.
